# Rectangular radar search in Google Places API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'd like to fetch a set of results based on a rectangular "radar" search. This is possible in the Javascript version by passing a LatLngBounds, but in the non-Javascript version there is only the location and radius options.

How can i do this? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The API is as documented, when a feature isn't supported you may send a [**feature-request**](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request)

The only option I see  is to request the places by defining a radius that encompasses the desired area and filter the results on your own.

Comment: Yeah that's what i am thinking too. but the radius has a max of 5 kilometers if im not mistaken? So i'll need to split the area in small rectangles. I was hoping there was a simpler solution.

Comment: the max-radius is 50km